# Eisenstein Series Convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, number-theory, convergence-divergence

In Eberhard Freitag's Complex Analysis, the author discusses how the Fourier Series of the Eisenstein series converges normally in $\mathbb{H}$ for $k\geq 2$, since $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (\sum_{d | n} d^{k-1})e^{2\pi i nz} \leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (n^k)e^{2\pi i nz}$. For reference, the Eisenstein series is given by $G_k(z) := \sum_{(c,d)\in \mathbb{Z}^2 \backslash (0,0)} \frac{1}{(cz+d)^k}$, and $\mathbb{H} = \{z\in \mathbb{C}: Im(z)>0\}$. However, Freitag warns that rearrangements must be performed carefully, as $\sum_{(c,d)\in \mathbb{Z}^2 \backslash (0,0)} |cz+d|^{-2}$ diverges while $\sum_{(c,d)\in \mathbb{Z}^2 \backslash (0,0)} |cz+d|^{-3}$ converges ($z\in \mathbb{H}$), yet provides no proof of these statements. If $z = x + yi$, then $y>k>0$ implies $|cz+d|^2 = (cx + d + cyi)(cx + d - cyi) = c^2x^2 + 2cxd + d^2 + c^2y^2 \geq c^2x^2 + 2cxd + d^2 + c^2k^2$, which works nicely for compact sets, but I believe we want normal convergence on all of $\mathbb{H}$.

I am not sure where to go from here, and it seems that holding $c$ constant and summing $d \to \infty$ should result in $\epsilon_1 \sum (\sum \frac{1}{n^2})$ and $\epsilon_2 \sum (\sum \frac{1}{n^3})$, which clearly diverge ($\epsilon_1, \epsilon_2$ are constants). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For $\Im(z)\ne 0$, $(c,d)\mapsto |cz+d|$ is a norm on $\Bbb{R}^2$ so $\sum_{(c,d)\in \Bbb{Z}^2} |cz+d|^{-r}$ converges for $r > 2$. The local uniform convergence follows from that $\inf_{c^2+d^2=1} |cz+d|$ is $>0$ and continuous in $z$ (for $z\in \Bbb{C-R}$)